# biblatex: Handling secondary ("quoted in") citations

Tags: biblatex, citing

> **This question and the answer became part of a package:**
>   [`biblatex-musuos`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-musuos)

How can I qoute secondary quotes which I’ve taken form another book.

### Example

Jon Doe writes a book an cites Fred Bloggs in it. Now I read the book of Doe an want to cite his cite of Bloggs. So my bibliography entry must look like

> Bloggs, Fred: A nice old book, 1850, p. 35. Quoted in Doe, John: A bad new Book, 2011, p. 67.

Doe’s book should not be listed separately in the bibliography.

I know that there’s a `bibstring` `quotedin` containing “quoted in” (p. 159 of `biblatex`’s manual) but I don’t know if theres a (predefined) way to use it …

### Update

It seems that there’s no predefined way, so I decided to use `userc` for crossreferences like this. This works for the bibliography but not for cite commands. At the moment I create the “in text cite” manually.

It would be great to have a macro like

```
\QIautocite[<prenote a>][<postnote a>]{<author a>}[<prenote b>][<postnote b>]{<author b>}
```

that expands to the above given example.

That’s my new code, which gives the right results for bibliography and “in text cite” but the latter not automatically …

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOKLET{autora,
  title = {A nice old book},
  userc={autorb},
  author = {Fred Bloggs},
  year = {1850},
}
@BOOKLET{autorb,
  title = {A bad new book},
  author = {Jon Doe},
  year = {2011},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{babel,csquotes,blindtext}

\usepackage[%
    bibstyle=authortitle,
    citestyle=verbose-ibid,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\NewBibliographyString{bibcitedas}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  bibcitedas = {{zitiert als}{zit. als}},
}

% Put the 'quoted in text' behind the bibentry.
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \ifbibliography{%
    \iffieldundef{userc}{}{%
      \newunit\bibstring{quotedin}\addspace\fullcite{\thefield{userc}}
    }
  }{}%
  \finentry%
}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{quotation}
    \blindtext\footnote{\cite[36]{autora}. Zit. nach \cite[89]{autorb}}
\end{quotation}
\blindtext\footnote{\cite[36]{autora}. Zit. nach \cite[89]{autorb}}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

### Example 2

In addition to my comment (Hi @Audrey. This works fine :-) but theres a little thing …) on Audrey’s answer:

If I use the `quotecite` command like this

```
\quotecite[1]{reese}[5]{weinberg}
\quotecite[1]{reese}[5]{weinberg}
\pagebreak
\quotecite[1]{reese}[5]{weinberg}
\quotecite[1]{reese}[5]{weinberg}
```

the footnotes should look like

> 1 Reese [full cite], p. 1. Zit. nach Weinberg [full cite], p. 65
>   2 Ebd.
>   ———— page break ————
>   3 Rese [short cite], p 1. Zit nach Weinberg [short cite], p. 65
>   4 Ebd.

Everything works like expected except footnote 3 which is

> 3 Rese [short cite], p 1. Zit nach Weinberg [**full** cite], p. 65

at the moment

### Update 2

Since it seems not possible to react to `autocite` I created a new plain command with

```
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\quoteciteplain}[\cbx@qcwrapperplain]{\cbx@quotecite}{\cbx@qcdelim}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@qcwrapperplain}[1]{%
  \global\toggletrue{cbx@isquote}%
  #1%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@isquote}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@iflastibid}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@ifquoteepost}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@ifquoterpost}}
```

Comment: Thanks for catching these problems, Tobi. The ibidem tracking scheme I initially wrote was unnecessarily complicated. The new approach is much more simple; it now has no effect ibidem in other citation commands.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some categories can help facilitate the output of quoted-in data and the suppression of "quoter" entries in the bibliography.

Your proposed "quoted-in" citation command can be defined via `\DeclareMultiCiteCommand`, where the delimiter can make use of `quotedin`. With some help from `etoolbox`, you can collect all of the quoted-in data through this new citation command and avoid the need to edit your `bib` file entirely.

The code below demonstrates these ideas, but accounts for the case where a quoter plays the role of a primary reference elsewhere. "Quotee"-only bibliography entries include quoted-in data. When a quotee has more than one quoter, the quoting entries are printed in the cite order. Quoter-only entries are suppressed. All other entries are treated normally.

Thanks to Tobi for finding bugs.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,ibidpage=true]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

% Just for demonstration. Above options are necessary, including
% default and verbose-ibid tracking options: opcittracker=false,
% loccittracker=false, idemtracker=false, citetracker=context,
% ibidtracker=constrict and pagetracker=true.
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{citepages=omit}

\NewBibliographyString{quotedfrom}
\NewBibliographyString{quotedon}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  quotedfrom = {zit\adddotspace aus},
  quotedon = {zit\adddotspace auf}}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{quoter}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{quotee}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{primary}

\defbibheading{quoter}[Quoters]{\section*{#1}}
\defbibheading{quotee}[Quotees]{\section*{#1}}
\defbibheading{citedasprimary}[Bibliography as desired]{\section*{#1}}

\defbibcheck{citedasprimary}{% Suppress quoter-only entries
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifcategory{quoter}}
               and not test {\ifcategory{quotee}}
               and not test {\ifcategory{primary}} }
    {\skipentry}
    {}}

\makeatletter

\newtoggle{cbx@isquote}% Current citation quotecite?
\newtoggle{cbx@iflastquote}% Last citation quotecite?
\newtoggle{cbx@fullquote}% Print a full quotecite?
\newtoggle{cbx@iflastibid}% Last quotecite ibid?
\newtoggle{cbx@ifquoteepost}% Ibid quotecite outputs quotee postnote?
\newtoggle{cbx@ifquoterpost}% Ibid quotecite outputs quoter postnote?

\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{% Add quoted-in data to quotee-only entries
  \ifbibliography
    {\ifboolexpr{ test {\ifcategory{quotee}}
                  and not test {\ifcategory{primary}} }
       {\newunit%
        \bibstring{quotedin}%
        \addspace%
        \global\toggletrue{cbx@isquote}%
        \fullcite{\csuse{cbx@quoter@\thefield{entrykey}}}%
        \global\togglefalse{cbx@isquote}}
       {}}
    {}%
  \finentry}

\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \iftoggle{cbx@isquote}
    {}
    {\addtocategory{primary}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
     \global\togglefalse{cbx@iflastquote}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:quotee}{%
  \savefieldcs{postnote}{cbx@post}%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifciteseen} and not test {\iftoggle{cbx@fullquote}} }
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\ifboolexpr{ not test {\iffirstonpage}
                     and test {\ifsamepage{\value{instcount}}{\value{instcount}-2}}
                     and test {\iftoggle{cbx@iflastquote}}
                     and test {\iffieldequalcs{entrykey}{cbx@lastquoteekey}} }
          {\printtext[bibhyperlink]{\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}%
           \iffieldequalcs{postnote}{cbx@lastquoteepost}
             {\clearfield{postnote}}
             {\global\toggletrue{cbx@ifquoteepost}}%
           \global\toggletrue{cbx@iflastibid}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:short}}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:full}}%
  \csxdef{cbx@lastquoteepost}{\csuse{cbx@post}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:quoter}{%
  \savefieldcs{postnote}{cbx@post}%
  \ifboolexpr{ not test {\iftoggle{cbx@fullquote}}
               and test {\iftoggle{cbx@iflastibid}}
               and test {\iffieldequalcs{entrykey}{cbx@lastquoterkey}} }
    {\iffieldequalcs{postnote}{cbx@lastquoterpost}
       {\clearfield{postnote}}
       {\global\toggletrue{cbx@ifquoterpost}}}
    {\iftoggle{cbx@iflastibid}
       {\quotedelim}
       {}%
     \global\togglefalse{cbx@iflastibid}%
     \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifciteseen} and not test {\iftoggle{cbx@fullquote}} }
       {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:short}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:full}}}%
  \csxdef{cbx@lastquoterpost}{\csuse{cbx@post}}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@ifquoteepost}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cbx@quotecite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifnumless{\value{multicitecount}}{2}% <loopcode>
     {\usebibmacro{citeindex}% Current entry is a quotee
      \addtocategory{quotee}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
      \xdef\cbx@quoteekey{\thefield{entrykey}}%
      \usebibmacro{cite:quotee}%
      \csxdef{cbx@lastquoteekey}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
     {\addtocategory{quoter}{\thefield{entrykey}}% Current entry is a quoter
      \xifinlistcs{\thefield{entrykey}}{cbx@quoterlist@\cbx@quoteekey}
        {}
        {\csxappto{cbx@quoter@\cbx@quoteekey}{\thefield{entrykey},}%
         \listcsxadd{cbx@quoterlist@\cbx@quoteekey}{\thefield{entrykey}}}%
      \usebibmacro{cite:quoter}%
      \csxdef{cbx@lastquoterkey}{\thefield{entrykey}}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\iftoggle{cbx@iflastibid}
     {\iftoggle{cbx@ifquoteepost}
        {\let\postnotedelim=\quoteepostdelim}
        {\iftoggle{cbx@ifquoterpost}
           {\let\postnotedelim=\quoterpostdelim}
           {}}}
     {}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:postnote}%
   \global\toggletrue{cbx@iflastquote}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\quotecite}
  [\cbx@qcwrapper\relax\mkbibfootnote]
  {\cbx@quotecite}
  {\cbx@qcdelim}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\fullquotecite}
  [\cbx@qcwrapper\cbx@mkfullquote\mkbibfootnote]
  {\cbx@quotecite}
  {\cbx@qcdelim}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\parenquotecite}
  [\cbx@qcwrapper\relax\mkbibparens]
  {\cbx@quotecite}
  {\cbx@qcdelim}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\plainquotecite}
  [\cbx@qcwrapper\relax\relax]
  {\cbx@quotecite}
  {\cbx@qcdelim}    

% Use first argument to override trackers, second to format
% the citation (e.g. \mkbibfootnote). The third is reserved
% for multicite output.
\newrobustcmd{\cbx@qcwrapper}[3]{%
  \global\toggletrue{cbx@isquote}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@fullquote}%
  #1#2{#3}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@isquote}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@iflastibid}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@ifquoteepost}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@ifquoterpost}}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@mkfullquote}{%
  \AtNextCite{\citetrackerfalse}%
  \toggletrue{cbx@fullquote}}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@qcdelim}{%
  \iftoggle{cbx@iflastibid}
    {}
    {\quotedelim}}

\newcommand*{\quoteepostdelim}{%
  \addcomma\space\bibstring{quotedfrom}\space}

\newcommand*{\quoterpostdelim}{%
  \addcomma\space\bibstring{quotedon}\space}

\newcommand*{\quotedelim}{%
  \adddot\space\bibsentence\bibstring{quotedin}\space}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\null\vfill\noindent
First primary cite.\footcite{augustine}
Same cite.\footcite{augustine}
Quoted-in cite.\quotecite[10--15]{reese}[5]{weinberg}
Same quoted-in cite.\quotecite[10--15]{reese}[5]{weinberg}
Same quoted-in cite, but different quotee
  postnote.\quotecite[10--15]{reese}[10]{weinberg}
Same quoted-in cite, but different quoter
  postnote.\quotecite(See)()[10--15]{reese}[11]{weinberg}
Same quoted-in cite, but different
  postnotes.\quotecite[26--28]{reese}[5--10]{weinberg}
\pagebreak

Same quoted-in cite, but on next
  page\quotecite(See)()[10--15]{reese}[11]{weinberg}.
Different quoted-in cite, both quotee and quoter cited
  elsewhere as primary.\quotecite(See)()[10]{massa}[540]{augustine}
Same quotee, different quotee postnote and different
  quoter.\quotecite[11]{massa}[540]{companion}
Primary cite, same as quotee (NB: ibidem not applied
  here)\footcite{massa}
New quoted-in cite.\quotecite(See)()[20]{shore}[11]{springer}
Same quotee, but different quoter.\quotecite[20]{shore}[100]{iliad}
Same, but full quoted-in cite.\fullquotecite[20]{shore}[100]{iliad}

\pagebreak
\printbibliography[category=quoter,heading=quoter]
\printbibliography[category=quotee,heading=quotee]
\printbibliography[check=citedasprimary,heading=citedasprimary]
\end{document}
```

Here are citations from the first page from the resulting document:
[image]

Citations from the second page:
[image]

The final bibliography:
[image]

Some notes on requested extensions and refinements of the original answer:

- Ibidem abbreviations. This extension isn't trivial; we need to examine two previous citations, but the existing citation tracker just looks at the last one. We can get around this by tracking the quoted-in citation manually, using some tests from both `biblatex` and `etoolbox`. A drawback of this approach is that use of ibidem for quoted-in citations is somewhat independent of the `biblatex` tracking options. Here I've attempted to mimic the default and `verbose-ibid` option settings.
- Inline citations. `verbose-ibid` is intended for primarily citations in footnotes, but inline versions of the quoted-in citation can be defined by altering the wrapper used in `\DeclareMultiCiteCommand`.
- "Full" citations. These can also be defined via the wrapper, provided that we have an additional flag to indicate that the citation should be printed with `cite:full`.

Comment: Thanks Audrey, that works great :-). The only little thing that’s missing is the combination with the ibidem mechanism. So if I cite with `Text\quotecite(Vgl.)()[36]{autora}[22]{autorb} Text\quotecite(Vgl.)()[36]{autora}[22]{autorb}` (i.e. the two cites follow immediately. The output could better be “[Footnote 1] Fullcite [Footnote 2] Ibidem.” Is that possible?

Comment: Hi @Audrey. This works fine :-) but theres a little thing I’d like to change. I even found the right place in your code but don’t know how to change it … Is it possible to get the _non first cite_ on a second page use `cite:short` instead of `cite:full`) The corresponding line in your code seems to be `{\usebibmacro{cite:full}}%` (line 14 of `\renewbibmacro*{cite}`). I guess the must be a toggle if it is the first time the source is mentioned (> `cite:full`) or a second, third, … time (> `cite:short`). Hope you understand what I mean …

Comment: See my 2nd example at my original question, that hopefully illustrates what I’d like to say.

Comment: That’s so great. There’s just a little bug left which I tried to fix but don’t find the right place to do it: At the footnotes there’s a doubled space between “Zit. nach” and “Weinberg” for example. In the Bibliography everything is right. Is it ok with you if I release your code as part of a `biblatex` style on CTAN. your name (I know only your username from here) will certainly be mentioned in the manual and in the code itself.

Comment: I’m not sure if I understand you right … I added your name (Audrey) and the link to this question to the manual an the `bbx`/`cbx` files. (The styles will be published under LPPL) Is that ok or do I have to to some more? If you like send me an e-mail (mail@tobias-weh.de) in fact that this isn’t relevant to the question …

Comment: Thank you again! As far as I can se everything is fine now :-)

Comment: Good to hear. Don't hesitate to let me know if you find anything else. I can't promise I'll be quick to fix any further problems, though!

Comment: OK: I thought I could do it my self but I don’t understand `biblatex` and your code enought. Is ist possible to make `\quotedcite` take care of the `autocite` option? My Ode was to simply toggle the `\mkbibfootnote{#1}` line of `\newrobustcmd{\cbx@qcwrapper}[1]{%` but I cant access the option value. See [How to access the value of a biblatex package option/key](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28142/how-to-access-the-value-of-a-biblatex-package-option-key)

Comment: `\autocite` can only be constructed from backend citation commands AFAIK. The verbose styles are footnote-based and `\quotecite` is very much dependent on the `verbose-ibid` style. Are you wanting to have an inline version of `\quotecite`? That could easily be done by declaring another `multicite` command, say `\inlinequotecite`, using a different wrapper.

Comment: Please see my update at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28142/how-to-access-the-value-of-a-biblatex-package-option-key

Comment: Now I created a new plain command, the also works withe the ibidem mechanism an thats ok. I thought I could create full cite plain command with adding `\citereset` or do you have a better idea?

Comment: The answer now allows you to define "full" versions of quoted-in citations. These avoid use of ibidem and output entry data via the macro `cite:full`.

Comment: @Audrey: Note that your answer has been converted to community wiki (CW) because you edited it 10 times. As CW, the answer will no longer generate reputation, and its upvotes seem to have been removed from your `biblatex` tag badge score. I suggest that you contact a moderator and ask  to "un-CW" your answer. (AFAIK, this is possible, but also a "first time" at tex.sx.)

Comment: @Audrey: Joseph Wright has resolved the issue. :-)

Comment: @lockstep Thanks to you and Joseph. Sorry for all the edits.

Comment: Hi, now I combined your answers and I’d like to upload my stil. But there’s one question left: Am I allowed to use your code? (I mentioned you and the link to this question in the manual and in the code itself furthermore I enclosed your code in a pseudo tag `<audrey>`.)

Comment: @Tobi Sure - that sounds fine. I sent you an email a few days ago. Feel free to write back if you need to discuss this further. I think we've cluttered this comment area enough as it is!

Comment: @Audrey: Sorry but your I don’t received your mail not even in the spam folder. The mail address I gave you above works, I tried it. Would you pleas be so kind and try to send it again? Maybe at both addresses (mail@tobias-weh.de and tobias_weh@arcor.de).

Comment: @Tobi OK. I just tried again.