# How to access the value of a biblatex package option/key

Tags: biblatex, key-value

Is it possible to access a value which is given as a bibliography option. For example if I have

```
\usepackage[somekey=foobar]{biblatex}
```

can I get the value (`foobar`) of `somekey` as a macro like `\KV@<family>@somekey`. I tried to find it out and had a look at `biblatex.sty` there i found the `\define@key` macro which is from `keyval.sty` as I know now. My search ended with the macro `\KV@blx@opt@pre@autocite{#1}` with which I could change the value but not get it.

As you can guess I’d like to get the value of the `autocite` option.

### Update

Maybe Joseph is right, so here is want I want: I want to be able to change the behavior of a macro according to the `autocite` option. The macro is `\quodecite` (see [biblatex: Handling secondary ("quoted in") citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27964/4918)) an since this is defined via `\DeclareMultiCiteCommand` I can’t use `\DeclareAutoCiteCommand` I guess. I could have asked Audrex this in the other question but I thought that I can solve it myself which leads to the question if I can access a key value …

### Update 2

At [biblatex: Handling secondary ("quoted in") citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27964/biblatex-handling-secondary-quoted-in-citations/28002#28002) Audrey suggested to build a extra command for the other `autocite` options, but I’d like to have an automatic solution.

This is the a part code to create the `\quotecite` command:

```
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\quotecite}[\cbx@qcwrapper]{\cbx@quotecite}{\cbx@qcdelim}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@qcwrapper}[1]{%
  \global\toggletrue{cbx@isquote}%
  \mkbibfootnote{#1}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@isquote}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@iflastibid}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@ifquoteepost}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@ifquoterpost}}
```

As on can imagine—and my tests proofed that—the output format (plain, footnote, …) of `\quotecite` could easily be change by replacing `\mkbibfootnote{#1}` by `\mkbibparens{#1}` for example. So my idea is to implement a conditional that takes care about the value of `autocite` and for that I need the value of the option.
Something like the following but in real LaTeX certainly would solve the problem I guess.

```
\newrobustcmd{\cbx@qcwrapper}[1]{%
  \global\toggletrue{cbx@isquote}%
  if (autocite=footnote)
    \mkbibfootnote{#1}%
    else if (autocite=parens)
      \mkbibparens{#1}
      else if (autocite=plain)
        #1
        else
          #1
          warning: unkown option of autocite for \quotecite
      end if
    end if
  end if
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@isquote}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@iflastibid}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@ifquoteepost}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@ifquoterpost}}
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that any particular option will store its value. More generally, you are trying to access the internals of a package, and one which is well-written enough to make this unnecessary in most cases. Perhaps you might explain the wider context of the request.

Comment: Not quite what I meant... `\quotecite` is tailored for `verbose-ibid`. `verbose-ibid`, like all the verbose styles, is intended for footnote citations. So I'm not sure why anyone would use anything other than `autocite=footnote`. Inline versions of `\quotecite` (regardless of `autocite`) might come in handy. My quibbling aside, I think the general question is still useful.

Comment: @Joseph: For the moment I’m going to provide an extra command for inline citing but as Audrey said the question is still interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\autocite` command depends on the `autocite` option setting and various citation commands. The latter is determined (in part) by the `citestyle` option. In `biblatex.sty` you can see how these options are handled. The value for `citestyle` is stored explicitly:

```
\define@key{blx@opt@ldt}{citestyle}{%
  \def\blx@cbxfile{#1}}
```

But the value for `autocite` isn't; it is instead used to identify a control sequence name using some commands from the `biblatex` and `etoolbox` packages.

```
\DeclareBibliographyOption{autocite}{%
  \ifcsundef{blx@acite@#1}
    {\blx@error
       {Autocite command '#1' undefined}
       {The autocite command '#1' has not been defined by
        the\MessageBreak selected citation style}}
    {\letcs\autocite{blx@acite@#1}%
     \letcs\autocites{blx@macite@#1}}}
```

The control sequences `blx@acite@plain`, `blx@macite@plain`, `blx@acite@inline`, etc. are defined in `biblatex.def` by:

```
\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{plain}{\cite}{\cites}
\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{inline}{\parencite}{\parencites}
\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{footnote}[f]{\smartcite}{\smartcites}
\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{superscript}[l]{\supercite}{\supercites}
```

Below is a very simple example of how you could create a format that depends on the `autocite` and `citestyle` options. It uses some commands from `etoolbox` and is constructed assuming the above generic definitions. These can later be redefined and expanded with further use of `\DeclareAutoCiteCommand`. So the test here isn't particularly comprehensive or robust to changes in the citation style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd{\mkbibautoformat}[1]{%
  \cslet{cbx@autocite}{\autocite}%
  \ifcsequal{cbx@autocite}{blx@acite@inline}
    {\ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdefstring{\blx@bbxfile}{numeric}}
                  or test {\ifdefstring{\blx@bbxfile}{alphabetic}} }
       {\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
       {\mkbibparens{#1}}}
    {\ifcsequal{cbx@autocite}{blx@acite@footnote}
       {\iffootnote
          {\ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdefstring{\blx@bbxfile}{numeric}}
                        or test {\ifdefstring{\blx@bbxfile}{alphabetic}} }
             {\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
             {\mkbibparens{#1}}}
          {\mkbibfootnote{#1}}}
       {\ifcsequal{cbx@autocite}{blx@acite@superscript}
          {\mkbibsuperscript{#1}}
          {#1}}}}
\makeatother

\DeclareCiteCommand{\autociteyear}[\mkbibautoformat]
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printfield{year}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill
\footnote{\autociteyear{companion}\autocite{companion}}
\end{document}
```

[image]