# How can I cite one ref in another reference?

Tags: citing, natbib

I would like to know how can I make a citation like this:

> (autor1, 2000 in autor2, 2010)

Is it possible in LaTeX without changing the format of all other citations?

Comment: Do you want this format? You can use an option to the reference using `\cite[\cite{...}]{...}`

Comment: Are you using `natbib`?

Comment: That options is not what Im looking for... there are no other way?

Comment: yes Im using natbib

Comment: Then, please see my answer below.

Comment: I had a similar question [biblatex: Handling secondary (“quoted in”) citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27964/4918) some time ago. The answer shows how to handle these quotes with biblatex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `natbib`, to get the exact format you described, you can use `\citetext` and `\citealp`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{xyzbiblio.bib}
@article{greenwade93, 
    author = "George D. Greenwade",
    title = "The {C}omprehensive {TeX} {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume = "14",
    number = "3",
    pages = "342--351",
    url=" www.ctan.org"
}

@book{knuth79,
    author = "Donald E. Knuth",
    title = "{TeX} and Metafont, New Directions in Typesetting",
    year = "1979",
    publisher = "American Mathematical Society and Digital Press",
    address = "Stanford"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\citetext{\citealp{greenwade93} in \citealp{knuth79}}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{xyzbiblio}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What about this other option: it is a little bit different

[image]

Comment: I cant even see it