# Nested citation following the Chicago manual of style

Tags: biblatex, classicthesis

I'm using the [classicthesis template](https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/wiki/Home) and my aim is to write a nested citation following the Chicago manual of style. I've started using the following command:

```
\mkbibparens{\citet[181]{bringhurst:2002}\postnotedelim cited by \citet{aurelius:2002}}
```

which results in (Bringhurst [2013, p. 181], cited by Aurelius [2002]).

However, to follow the Chicago style the desired output should be with commas:  (Bringhurst, 2013, p. 181, cited by Aurelius, 2002). This can be achieved using the following command. But I was wondering if there's a more generic way to achieve this?

```
\mkbibparens{\citeauthor{bringhurst:2002}, \citeyear[181]{bringhurst:2002}\postnotedelim cited by \citeauthor{aurelius:2002}, \citeyear{aurelius:2002}}
```

Here's a MWEB:

```
\documentclass[
  twoside,
  openright,
  titlepage,
  numbers=noenddot,
  headinclude,
  footinclude=true, 
  cleardoublepage=empty,
  fontsize=11pt,
  ngerman,
  american,
]{scrbook}
%\input{classicthesis-config}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\PassOptionsToPackage{%----citation settings------------
  %backend=biber, %instead of bibtex
    backend=bibtex8,bibencoding=ascii,%
    language=auto,%
    %style=numeric-comp,%
  style=authoryear-comp, % Author 1999, 2010
  %bibstyle=authoryear,dashed=false, % dashed: substitute rep. author with ---
  sorting=nyt, % name, year, title
  maxbibnames=2, % default: 3, et al.
  %backref=true,%
  natbib=true % natbib compatibility mode (\citep and \citet still work)
}{biblatex}
    \usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{TeX.bib} % bibliography
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{TeX.bib}
        @book{diller97,
        author = "Antoni Diller",
        title = "{\LaTeX} Line by Line",
        year = "1997",
        edition = "1st",
        publisher = "Wiley",
        address = "Chichester, England"
    }

    @book{goossens99,
        author = "Michel Goossens and Sebastian Rahtz",
        title = "The {\LaTeX} Web Companion",
        year = "1999",
        edition = "1st",
        publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
        address = "Boston, Massachusetts"
    }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\chapter{Test}
\mkbibparens{\citet[181]{diller97}\postnotedelim cited by \citet{goossens99}}

\section{Chicago style}
\mkbibparens{\citeauthor{goossens99}, \citeyear[181]{goossens99}\postnotedelim cited by \citeauthor{diller97}, \citeyear{diller97}}    

This doesn't work:
\citep[p.~181, cited by \protect \citealp{diller97}]{goossens99}

\section{Add some content}
\lipsum[1-2]

\printbibliography[heading=classicthesis]
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** Changed the MWE so the .sty file is not needed anymore. 
(The classicthesis-config.sty file can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/src).)

Hope that helps to clarify the problem.

Comment: Could you add  a minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)), that illustrates your problem?

Comment: Do you get what you want if you use `\cite` instead of your `\citet`? (This is a guess, Bobyandbob's request is still the solid way to go).

Comment: In general you can't nest citation commands, so you have to find another way. See [biblatex: Handling secondary (“quoted in”) citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27964/35864), [What is the most elegant way to cite two things connected by a 'joining word' with biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/213185/35864)

Comment: @gusbrs indeed the `\cite` does the trick! Many thanks! Uff almost too simple... I'll put the solution in the example

Comment: To close this I wonder if @gusbrs wants to provide the solution as an answer, should I answer it myself or omit the question as the answer is that simple?

Comment: Do not put the solution into your question. You can ask gusbrs to post an answer (if he doesn't want to, you can write one yourself, but don't put the solution into the question). If you think your question is not going to help future visitors and is not of general interest, you can also opt to delete/close the question.

Comment: Thanks @moeve, I'll give it a couple of days to see if gusbrs will provide an answer. In terms of relevance to me this is a generic and simple solution to the problem that I haven't found in any of the answers linked to the question. So hope it'll be of help for someone in the future.

Comment: Ideally, just ping him.

Comment: @gusbrs Do you want to write up an answer here? Your suggestion seems to have been the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could adapt your attempt using `\cite` instead of `\citet`, as:

```
\mkbibparens{\cite[181]{diller97}\postnotedelim cited by \cite{goossens99}}
```

Resulting in:

[image]

This might "get the job done", however it is far from ideal to go about stitching cite commands like this along your document, especially if you must do it frequently. In this last case, a closer look at the links provided by moewe in the comments would be a good idea.