# Is there a way to cite author of quotes?

Tags: biblatex, citing, sharelatex, quoting

I am trying to implement a quote in my text, but the quote has a different author than the author of the book. Can I simply cite the book, and not the original author? Is it a way to cite the "correct" author in a quote, without adding to bibliography?

Comment: How about adding a footnote, including the author name, to the end of the quote?

Comment: Your setup isn't entirely clear. Is it, say, that person A (the author of a book) quotes some (presumably unpublished) statement by person B?

Comment: I would cite the original author, but then mark it **as cited in …** the book you've consulted. You need to do this, since you have not actually checked the original quote and the quote might be wrong or used out of context. I would always try and source the original quote if possible. Expample: `\cite[A. N. Author as cited in][56]{bookkey}`

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27964/35864

Comment: Any news here? It is not entirely clear to me what you want to do. As it stands right now your question is a duplicate of the question I linked above.

Comment: Any news here? Did the link help? Did you have something else mind? Would `\cite[A. N. Author as cited in][56]{bookkey}` be enough?

Comment: @DavidPurton Do you want to type up a quick answer here, please?

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion is to attribute the quote to the original author, but mark it as *quoted in* or *cited in* whatever source you consulted. `biblatex` includes the `quotedin` string for this purpose.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{packer:1991,
  author = {Packer, J. I.},
  title = {Among God's Giants},
  subtitle = {The Puritan Vision of the Christian Life},
  location = {Eastbourne},
  publisher = {Kingsway},
  date = {1991}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[australian]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\SetCiteCommand{\autocite}
\begin{document}
  \null\vfill
  Richard Baxter writes
  \blockcquote[\bibstring{quotedin}][91]{packer:1991}[.]{If heaven be too high
  for you to think on, and to provide for, it will be too high for you ever to
  possess}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]